# Input type file doesn’t work with Android 6

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following html code `<ion-input type="file" accept=".csv, .txt" (change)="readFile($event)"></ion-input>`

When running it on the browser (windows) using vscode/ionic serve, everything is working perfectly. When running on the device (Android 6.01) after installing the apk file, the screen makes a small "jump" of its content and then it goes back but nothing else happens. Clicking again does nothing until I focus another field and then click the button again, then the small jump happens again and so on...

When checking the app permissions, I see storage as disabled so I enabled it but still, nothing happens.

I read about a lot of problems with Android 4.4 and 4.4.2 but I have 6.01. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: If you need to access files, you will need to use cordova plugins/ionic native plugin for File access like [FileChooser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/).

Comment: Thanks! So what input file type is used for? also, FileChooser is only for Android, what about iOS?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upload-file-with-input-type-file-but-get-it-with-file-path/100043/2 input type file is not supported in mobile

Comment: you could try https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin

Comment: thanks, and I guess I should call either one depending on the platform I'm running now...